# ggplotly() does not display geom_vline / geom_hline when data is POSIXct

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, posixct, geom-vline

I am trying to make a graph with "time markers". These time markers are vertical lines for certain dates. Time data are POSIXct format. I would like to use the awesome interactive interface of Plotly and use my ggplot objects in it.

The problem is that these "time markers" doesn't show in after using ggplotly(). I ave already tried with `plotly::add_segments()` but it does not work.
Here are two reproductible examples :

**1. With non-POSIXct data it works fine**

> ```
> # dummy dataset
> df2 = data.frame(id = 1:10, measure = runif(10, 0, 20))
> events2 = data.frame(number = c(2,3,8))
> # ggplot graph
> p2 = ggplot() + geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = id, y = measure))  +
>   geom_vline(data = events2, aes(xintercept = events2$number), color = "red")
> p2
> # plotly graph that displays the geom_vline properly
> ggplotly(p2)
> ```

**2. With POSIXct data is doesn't display the correct result**

> ```
> # dummy dataset
> df = data.frame(date = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-07-01", tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
>                            as.POSIXct("2018-04-15", tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
>                            "1 month"),
>                 measure = runif(10, 0, 20))
> events = data.frame(date_envents = as.POSIXct(c("2017-10-12", "2017-11-12", "2018-03-15"), tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
> # ggplot graph
> p = ggplot() + geom_line(data = df, aes(x = date, y = measure))  +
>   geom_vline(data = events, aes(xintercept = events$date), color = "red")
> p
> # plotly graph that does not display the geom_vline properly
> ggplotly(p)
> ```

I have seen some workaround (like this one : [Add vertical line to ggplotly plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754080/add-vertical-line-to-ggplotly-plot)) but it is "complicated". Is there a more simple way to solve this problem ?

I am using Windows 10 with R version 3.5.0,  RStudio and the following packages :
`library(tidyverse)` and `library(plotly)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A simple workaround is to set the `xintecept` of the `geom_vline` to numeric.

**sample data**

```
df = data.frame(date = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-07-01", tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                           as.POSIXct("2018-04-15", tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                           "1 month"),
                measure = runif(10, 0, 20))
events = data.frame(date_envents = as.POSIXct(c("2017-10-12", "2017-11-12", "2018-03-15"), tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

**code**

```
p = ggplot() + geom_line(data = df, aes(x = date, y = measure))  +
  geom_vline(data = events, aes(xintercept = as.numeric(events$date)), color = "red")
```

**result**

```
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this, that's great.  The only problem is that the label on the vertical lines shows the numeric transformation rather than the date.  Is there a way to force the label to the date format?

Comment: @chrisjacques probably as easy as using `as.Date` on the labels

Comment: sadly no, i did try that but  it looks like `label` is not an accepted parameter in geom_vline.  I tried both `geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(my_dates),
             label = as.Date(tmy_dates))`  and  `vline(xintercept = as.numeric(my_dates),
             aes(label = as.Date(my_dates)))`

Comment: @chrisjacques See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150087/ggplotly-fails-with-geom-vline-with-xintercept-date-value) for a working solution. Seems like the `text` aesthetic is able to do the trick.