# How to keep "geom_vline" during converting plot from "ggplot" to "ggplotly"?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am losing "geom_vline" during converting plot from "ggplot" to "ggplotly".

How to keep it and correctly convert plot object?

Here is the code

```
# Data set
df <- data.table(
  date = as.Date(c(
    "2020-12-28", "2020-12-30", "2021-10-11", "2022-11-11", "2023-12-13")),
  value = c(
    100, 120, 200, 180, 150))

# Create 'ggplot'
g <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(se = FALSE) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date("2021-10-11"), linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +
  annotate("text", x = as.Date("2021-10-11"), y = Inf, label = "label", vjust = 1, hjust = -0.1, color = "red") +
  theme_minimal()

# There is vertical line here
g

# Convert to 'ggplotly'
g_plotly <- ggplotly(g, tooltip = c("text")) %>% config(displayModeBar = FALSE)

# Lost vertical line
g_plotly
```

Comment: Try `xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date("2021-10-11"))`. See [Add vertical line to ggplotly plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754080/add-vertical-line-to-ggplotly-plot)

Comment: You will also need to specify a y position for your annotation (say 350). `plotly` will drop `Inf` values, so you can't use them to position a label at the top of your panel.